# Error: No space left on device when reloading iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

Centos7 machine

systemctl reload iptables
returns
Error: No space left on device

But if I can believe iptables.log - it has been reloaded

```
May  6 13:52:26 sis iptables.init: iptables: Trying to reload firewall rules: [  OK  ]

df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        63G   72K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        63G  4.1G   59G   7% /run
tmpfs                        63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127                  215G  175G   38G  83% /
/dev/md126                 1008M  150M  807M  16% /boot
/dev/md125                  917G  828G   81G  92% /data
tmpfs                        13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                        13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1005
tmpfs                        13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1001

 df -i
Filesystem                   Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs                   16476763     480 16476283    1% /dev
tmpfs                      16479004      30 16478974    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      16479004     850 16478154    1% /run
tmpfs                      16479004      13 16478991    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127                 14319616  716623 13602993    6% /
/dev/md126                    65664     340    65324    1% /boot
/dev/md125                 61046784 9323710 51723074   16% /data
tmpfs                      16479004     227 16478777    1% /run/user/0
tmpfs                      16479004       2 16479002    1% /run/user/1005
tmp
fs                      16479004      21 16478983    1% /run/user/1001
```

Some idea - what can be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: ENOSPC is an error that can be returned by any number of system calls. You must not assume it means "disk full". It could be an error returned by the iptables command (here's a random example, which is unrelated to OP's case: https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg59816.html ), but without context it's difficult to know.

Comment: Make sure that drives are mounted in read-write mode. I had a few issues where a VPS would boot in read-only mode (for some weird reasons)